# Animating the drawn line

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I am using the following code to draw a line and it works well:

```
var centerX =  $("#myCanvas").width()/ 2;
var centerY = $("#myCanvas").height()/ 2;
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,centerY );
ctx.lineTo( centerX*2,centerY);
ctx.stroke();
```

Now I want to animate the line while it is drawn but I do not know how to do it.I tried to do it with animate but I could not .Can anyone help?

Here is the fiddle link as well:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvTSL/)

Comment: Perhaps this tutorial would help: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/

Comment: If you want full control over it you should make a looping function like when you would make a game. something like setInterval(function() { animationLoop(); }, 1000 / fps); and than add some value each time that function gets called than redraw it

Comment: You may also want to check out EaselJS (and its sibling project, TweenJS). It greatly simplifies the process of creating canvas elements. If you want to do it from scratch, though, the basic concept is that you loop through a main "game loop," and each time you go through the loop, you repaint the canvas and the redraw the line based on some preset velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use linear interpolation (lerping) to calculate the points on a line from start to end.**

```
    var cx=canvas.width/2;
    var cy=canvas.height/2;
    var pct=0.50;

    // calc the value that is x% between a & b

    var lerp=function(a,b,x){ return(a+x*(b-a)); };

    // use lerping to calc the value of x at the midpoint (50%) of the line

    var x=lerp(0,cx*2,pct);
```

**Then you can incrementally draw a line from start to end with the requestAnimationFrame loop.**

```
function animate(){
    if(pct<100){requestAnimationFrame(animate);}
    var x=lerp(0,cx*2,pct/100);
    drawLine(0,cy,x,cy);
    pct++;    
}
```

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6P6jx/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cx=canvas.width/2;
    var cy=canvas.height/2;
    var lerp=function(a,b,x){ return(a+x*(b-a)); };
    var pct=0;

    animate();

    function animate(){
        if(pct<100){requestAnimationFrame(animate);}
        var x=lerp(0,cx*2,pct/100);
        drawLine(0,cy,x,cy);
        pct++;    
    }

    function drawLine(x0,y0,x1,y1){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
        ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```